# What else might be causing battery drain on my Android 6.0.1?

Tags: battery

My Galaxy SC-04F, not rooted, recently upgraded to Android 6. Since then, it runs really hot and the battery drains very fast.

I looked for solutions on the net, and I found two suggestions:

Clear the app cache in Settings -> Storage -> Internal Storage ->Cached data

Rebooting into recovery and clearing the system cache.

I did both of these, and my phone was almost immediately noticeably cooler, and the battery was definitely not draining as fast.

Unfortunately, this only lasted about 24 hours. The next day or so, my phone felt hot again, and the battery was draining fast.

I checked online again, and some people said there was a 6.0.1 update that solved some kind of bug. I checked Settings - About this device, and it says my Android version is 6.0.1 already.

What else can I do to try and get my phone to run normally and not overheat with excessive battery drain?

Comment: Does the battery usage in settings show anything interesting?

Comment: @Madushan, thanks for responding. Currently, "Android System" is the top energy user, at 28%. Which seems odd. In my experience, usually the screen is the number one energy consumer.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the answer to my question.

When my phone was hot and losing battery power quickly, I checked `Settings -> Battery - Battery Usage`, and would see that "Android System" was the #1 power consumer.

I would then go to `Settings - Developer Options -> Running Services` and look for any services under the name "Android System" and with the same icon. There was only one, so I click on that to see more details and I can see that there is a service called "**AtFwdService**".

Stopping this service often helped, so it seems to be the power consuming culprit. However, there is one additional step that often seems to be necessary:

After stopping the **AtFwdService** process, I then us an app called "Smart Manager" which has an option to clear applications out of RAM (there are probably other ways of doing this, this just happens to be the way I've done it). I use "Clear All", because, I have learned that even though the "AtFwdService" doesn't show as an entry, and even after stopping it, it still seems to be in memory somehow.

Once I've cleared the memory, my phone cools down and power consumption slows down to something more normal.